# Russian language in e-TextEditor or Cygwin

Tags: windows, encoding, utf-8, cygwin, e-texteditor

I'm using e-TextEditor for some tasks and can't figure, why when i using some Russian text and process it in bundle script i'm always getting something like http://gyazo.com/f38c69babe1f95ff786711fe684aee77.png . I'm think this is cygwin bug, because webkit must render it correct in UTF-8 encoding. I'm tested some guides thats describes how to enable correct Russian encoding in cygwin, but with no results. I'm running Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I think this question belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest Cygwin version 1.7? Previous versions do not support UTF-8, but it's the default in 1.7.

Comment: Yes. I'm installed latest version and all works fine, except when i using it from e-TextEditor. Also it's cant display name of my computer, because it's has Russian symbols.

Comment: What are the locale and charset set to in your Cygwin environment? Probably a mismatch between that and whatever E is using. (They're set via LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, or LANG).

Answer (score 0):

I HAD problem visualising Russian text from a program running on Windows Pro 10. I just open control, clock & regions, region and administrative. When yo see "Language for non-Unicode programs" just click "Change system locale..." and select the language. Restart computer and this is all.

I can see Russian text in software installed on Windows 10 Pro and the operating systems keeps same language; in my case English.